# Python AST : TypeError Rewriting Node

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to create an equation solver from scratch using PLY and Python's ASTs.

Beginning with the input `2 + x` I first translate to `N.Number(2) + x`. Why? Because I'm using my own Class for Real Numbers.

Now, I'm creating an AST from the output of the first step. Here, I want to rewrite the 'x', changing its Name Node by a Function Call Node to get something like this: `N.Number(2) + N.Number(42)`.

But I get this TypeError :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ast.py", line 52, in <module>
    print(eval(compile(yop, filename="", mode="eval")))
TypeError: required field "value" missing from Attribute
```

This is my code so far:

```py
class RewriteName(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if node.id == 'x':
            return ast.copy_location(ast.Call(func=ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name(id='N', ctx=ast.Load()), attr='Number', ctx=ast.Load()),
                args=[ast.Num(n=42)],
                keywords=[]
            ), node)

question = "N.Number(2) + x"
yop = ast.parse(question, mode="eval")

print(ast.dump(yop))
RewriteName().visit(yop)
print(ast.dump(yop))

print(eval(compile(yop, filename="", mode="eval")))
```

The problem is obviously coming from the Rewrite_Name class. Notice the two prints around it : these are their outputs :

```
Expression(body=BinOp(left=Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='N', ctx=Load()), attr='Number', ctx=Load()), args=[Num(n=2)], keywords=[]), op=Add(), right=Name(id='x', ctx=Load())))

Expression(body=BinOp(left=Call(func=Attribute(attr='Number', ctx=Load()), args=[Num(n=2)], keywords=[]), op=Add(), right=Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='N', ctx=Load()), attr='Number', ctx=Load()), args=[Num(n=42)], keywords=[])))
```

My cal to the Rewrite_Name class is wrongfully changing something from the left part of the BinOp of the Expression but I don't know why.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you get this error because when you visit the first Name, its id is not x. In this code, your function `visit_Name` returns `None`.

Adding a `else: return node`

```py
class RewriteName(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if node.id == 'x':
            return ast.copy_location(ast.Call(func=ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name(id='N', ctx=ast.Load()), attr='Number', ctx=ast.Load()),
                args=[ast.Num(n=42)],
                keywords=[]
            ), node)
        else:
            return node
```

Will help you avoid the `required field "value" missing from Attribute`...

Just to get another `TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from expr` ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @nilleb : You get the first part indeed ! I just added ```yop = ast.fix_missing_locations(yop)```to fix locations and everything is working just fine ! :)